# Help with awk to truncate and pad

Tags: php, awk

I have a long list of Unicode values that are semi-colon delimited.  Here's an example:

```
E0027;TAG APOSTROPHE;Cf;0;BN;;;;;N;;;;;
```

All I need is the "E0027;" part.

So I first need to drop everything in the line AFTER the first semicolon, but in some cases the semicolon is after 4 digits, in other cases, (as above) it's after 5.  If it were the same throughout I'd just truncate after a fixed number of chars.  I've found lots of examples for doing various manipulations with awk but no regular expressions that seem to fit this particular case.  Does anyone know what the proper syntax is?  The logic is merely to keep everything BEFORE the first semicolon and to drop everything after it.

Then, for the resulting file, I need to add a leading 0 to the line if the number is only 4 chars.  So for example:

```
8A9B;
```

Should become:

```
08A9B;
```

But the 5 digit values (such as the first example) should remain as is...no leading zero.

(Though would an extra leading zero make a difference if I'm using these values in HTML?  Would it matter if I had:

```
&#x0E0027
```

Instead of:

```
&#xE0027
```

If these will be parsed identically by PHP and won't make a difference, I guess the latter part isn't so important (though with thousands of extra zeros it will bloat the size of the code.)

Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: Does the optional leading zero need to come before the 'E' or after the 'E'? Because your examples are ambiguous about that.

Comment: Never mind, I understand your examples now. ;-)

Comment: @fireeyedboy:  I see why it's a little confusing but the examples are correct -- the 0 would be _before_ the "E" because otherwise it would actually be a different number entirely.  I was mainly just wondering if (to a computer) the difference between "0E0027" and "E0027" is the same as the difference between "0100" and "100" (the difference being none in the latter case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F';' '$0=length($1)<5?"0" $1 FS:$1 FS'
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ echo "8A9B;TAG APOSTROPHE;Cf;0;BN;;;;;N;;;;;" | awk -F';' '$0=length($1)<5?"0" $1 FS:$1 FS'
08A9B;

$ echo "E0027;TAG APOSTROPHE;Cf;0;BN;;;;;N;;;;;" | awk -F';' '$0=length($1)<5?"0" $1 FS:$1 FS'
E0027;
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Awk code fixed to leave last ';' in place.

```
print -- "E0027;TAG APOSTROPHE;Cf;0;BN;;;;;N;;;;;
0027;TAG APOSTROPHE;Cf;0;BN;;;;;N;;;;;" \
| awk '{
        #dbg print "$0=" $0
        sub(/;.*$/, ";")  # fixed here
        len=length($0)
        if (len == 5) {print "0" $0} # this was 4, now 5 with ';'
        else if (len == 6) {print $0} # 5 changed to 6
        else {print "error in input: found len=" len " in XX" $0 "xx"}
}'
```

you can replace the `print -- "... " |` with `cat file |`  OR avoid a UUOC award and remove `print -- "..." |` AND append `inFileName > outFileName` after the last `'` of the awk program.

I don't know the anwser to your HTML question.

Comment: I like this answer because it's actually possible to see where the logic decisions are being made, but I'm unable to run it somehow -- I tried copying as is into a command line, and I tried copying each line one by one...either way it gives syntax errors.  But if I can get it to work (in the BASH shell) then this would be great because for the future, I can change the "print "0" $0" part to whatever I want if I decide to use other prefixes.  That's very useful.  I'm probably doing something wrong in just typing it.  Is it meant to be inside a shell script, perhaps?  Maybe I'll try that...Thx!

Comment: I did get this to work in a shell script!  Thank you!  However, I noticed that it's stripping off the final semicolon, which I need.

Comment: @Dave : Sorry that you had a problem with getting the script to work. But is was good learning experience, yes ;-? I have modified the script to append a ; at the end of the line (but I haven't tested it), so let me know if there is a problem.   A different solution to this would be to add the ';' char at the end of each print statement, i.e. `print "0" $0 ";"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm no *nix man, so not really familiar with awk. However, if a php solution is acceptable, how about this:

```
$values = array();
$lines = file( '/path/to/file', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES );
foreach( $lines as $line )
{
    // get part before first occurence of ;
    $value = strstr( $line, ';', true ); 
    // pad the value, if applicable
    $value = str_pad( $value, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );
    // put it in the result array
    $values[] = $value;
}
```

And if reading the entire file into memory at once is unacceptable, you could read it line by line, with `fopen()`, `fgets()`, etc. of course.

Comment: After some editing, but reviewing your question again, my first answer stands.

Comment: We're talking command line PHP here, aren't we? Hmm, in that case this example might not be so useful. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "E0027;TAG APOSTROPHE;Cf;0;BN;;;;;N;;;;;" | awk -F";" '{ printf "%05s\n",$1 }'
E0027
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the zero-pad flag doesn't work on the string specifier. Wish it did. You'll have to go about it with `substr()` like belisarius did

Comment: well, I may be misinterpreting what you say. `echo "E0027;TAG APOSTROPHE;Cf;0;BN;;;;;N;;;;;" | awk -F";" '{ printf "%010s\n",$1 }'`

Comment: It doesn't zero-pad, it space-pads. At least with `gawk`

Comment: hmm...my output was `00000E0027`, when the above was run. It zero pads. Unless my eyes are playing tricks on me, or i am still misinterpreting what you are trying to say.

Comment: @kurumi interesting enough, I see that ideone shows the zero-pad.  Apparently this was a bug that was fixed in either 3.1.7 or 3.1.8. I'll need to check the changelogs.  But strings should be space-padded

Comment: @SiegeX, if you look at gawk man page (ver 3.17+), ` 0      A  leading 0 (zero) acts as a flag, that indicates output should be padded with zeroes instead of spaces.  This applies even to
              non-numeric output formats.`

Comment: @kurumi: found it *"Tue Aug  4 06:04:23 2009  Arnold D. Robbins  <arnold@skeeve.com>

        * builtin.c (format_tree): zero_flag does not apply to
        %c and %s conversions. Thanks to Mike Brennan and Thomas Dickey
        for the bug report."* It was fixed in 3.1.8

Comment: This did not work for me.  If I run it with the above example, it strips off the final semicolon.  If I run it with a 4 digit example, it returns a space (as SiegeX noted) instead of a zero, and also strips off the semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN {FS="\;"}

{print substr("0000" $1 FS, length($1),6)}
```

Input:

> E0027;TAG APOSTROPHE;Cf;0;BN;;;;;N;;;;;
>      8A9B;TAG APOSTROPHE;Cf;0;BN;;;;;N;;;;;

Out:

> E0027;
>     08A9B;

Running at [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/clone/hVt8g).

Comment: What you really want is `awk -F';' '$0=substr("0000" $1 FS, length($1),6)'`

Comment: @Siege I did not intend to write a command line, but a program file in awk to be executed as _awk -f_

Comment: That's fine but you forgot the `FS` and thus length 6. Also, the semi-colon doesn't need to be escaped because its not special in regex

Comment: @Siegex Yep. I forgot the OP wants a final ";"